# popup loading window

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup, popupwindow

I want a popup screen to show the user that "this part" or "that part" of my app is loading....A lot of things within my app is referenced content so sometimes it takes a sec to load...

I'm new to Ajax (so pardon me, please), but I want a popup window to appear to the user in Ajax or JavaScript to let the user know the app is "loading" when the user finger taps something that needs to load....For example content on the new screen....I hope I'm making sense here.... I don't know where to start when it comes to making this happen (cause I'm not a code warrior yet, still a bit green sry lol), so any help is appreciated. I'm using JavaScript and HTML5 so far, but I need a popup loading window widget...

Comment: Java!=JavaScript -- tag removed.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something along the lines of colorbox.js (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox). In more general terms, what you're looking for is a modal dialog box. Modal dialog boxes can be contrasted with more basic dialog boxes that don't grey out the rest of the screen. jQuery UI includes such a dialog, which you can see here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Of course, these aren't going to give you a loading effect out of the box. You'll have to write code to check whatever loading conditions pertain to your app, then dismiss the dialog box. A very simple way to do this would be to use setTimeout in conjunction with an ajax call whose success handler dismisses the dialog box. Or, if you don't have a way to track your loading status, you could just use a simple dialog to prompt the user to wait (but that's not particularly nice for the user).